# Displaying a multi-valued column using a tabular UI

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm hoping to display a multi-valued column in a tabular UI format.  By multi-valued column, I mean a column in which a single cell can simultaneously have multiple values -- aka a list of values.  These values might be drawn from a short list of possibilities (e.g. an enumeration) or from a long list (e.g. another table).  Imagine a table of contacts with a "friends" column that can refer to zero or more other contacts.

I need the ability to add new values, remove values, and ideally the values would be listed horizontally and word wrapped.  I have a feeling that no out-of-the-box datagrid control on the planet can do this, but I figured this is the right forum to ask such a question.

I'm guessing that the current state of the art is to display the information in a form, not in a table (e.g. "details" of a row).  However, we would like to actually display the values in a column of the table in a horizontally wrapped, in-line editable fashion.  At this time, we are planning to use WPF, so I'm hoping for a WPF solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF is definitely the right tool for this job. I don't think you'll find it very difficult to get the layout you want once you understand a few core WPF concepts (mostly binding and DataTemplates). I would suggest maybe a [ListView/GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747048.aspx) with a GridViewColumn with a custom CellTemplate containing an ItemsControl with its own DataTemplate...Simple, really ;-)

Comment: as I read the question, the OP is looking for a NON-custom, off the shelf, CellTemplate (or whatever) to do this.

Comment: Your suggestion ended up being right on.  The Telerik winforms controls looked promising on the surface but failed to solve my problem.  In the end we're doing WPF.